# Python program runs thread in another Python program, can't see global variable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, global-variables, global

I have one Python program running another module (SqRt, in a different Python file, dumb_waiter.py) as a thread. The thread/module does run, it prints a few comments to let me know. However, the top level program that is calling it is not seeing a global variable (Result) that it (SqRt) has created. If I have both bits of code in the same Python file, all is ok.

I am actually trying to capture an image on an RPi in response to a button press, all works with poling the line, but getting it to run as a thread is not (poling is every frame, so if frame rate is very low, it can miss a button press).

Code below is some test code, very simple. It calls SqRt in dumb_waiter.py (messing around, the names are screwy). It serves no purpose other than to allow me to focus on the issue of the variables' visibility.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from dumb_waiter import SqRt
Result = False

Result1 = Thread(target = SqRt, args = ("sqrt 2", 2))
Result1.start()
while not Result:
    pass
print("test dumb_waiter, output is", Result)
```

Next is program dumb_waiter.py. I add a random delay 1 to 10 secs, so I can easily visualise more than 1 thread running.....:-

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from random import randint # this should be in the module below, but it works

def SqRt(VarName, MyNo):
    global Result
    Result = False
    Wait = randint(1,10)
    print("wait", Wait, "seconds")
    time.sleep(Wait)
    Result = [VarName, MyNo ** 0.5]
    print("dumb_waiter result is", Result)
    return
```

The above produces the following output:-

wait 2 seconds

dumb_waiter result is ['sqrt 2', 1.4142135623730951]

Clearly the thread is working, but I cannot see the global variable Result from the earlier code that is calling dumb_waiter.py, and am therefore not executing the print("test dumb_waiter, output is", Result) instruction in the top level code. As I say, put it all in a single Python file and it all works fine.....

So, how do I create a variable that the threaded code modifies, and the top level code can see, when the two programs are in different Python files?

Answer (score 0):

In `dumb_waiter.py`, when you write `global Result`, you aren't referring to the variable called `Result` in your first file. Referring to this variable would be difficult without introducing a circular dependency.

One way to do this is to create a third file, `shared_variable.py`:

```
Result = False
```

Then in `dumb_waiter.py`:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import shared_variable
from random import randint # this should be in the module below, but it works

def SqRt(VarName, MyNo):
    shared_variable.Result = False
    Wait = randint(1,10)
    print("wait", Wait, "seconds")
    time.sleep(Wait)
    shared_variable.Result = [VarName, MyNo ** 0.5]
    print("dumb_waiter result is", Result)
    return
```

And in `test.py`:

```
import time
import shared_variable
from threading import Thread
from dumb_waiter import SqRt

Result1 = Thread(target = SqRt, args = ("sqrt 2", 2))
Result1.start()
while not shared_variable.Result:
    pass
print("test dumb_waiter, output is", shared_variable.Result)
```

This is fairly close to your original code, and it should work, but it's a bad idea because the `while` loop is busy-waiting. A better idea would be to call `join` on the running thread.

Comment: Good point about joining the thread. In the real program I will still be poling the result (between frames) to see if the button has been pressed. I have solved the problem, with a (in my opinion) very inelegant solution. I have added    import dumb_waiter as d # to minimise typing later.    from dumb_waiter import *     then referred to Result as d.Result. Sorry, can't seem to get a cr, so layout is poor.